# Code to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have this code in PHP. I want to convert the syntax to JavaScript. Could you help me?

```
$id = "";
$auth_token = "";
    if (preg_match("/&id\=([^&]+)/", $profile_url, $matches)):
    $id = $matches[1];
    preg_match("/&authToken\=([^&]+)/", $profile_url, $matches);
    $auth_token = $matches[1];
endif;
```

I've tried this code:

```
var name, publicUrl, location, industry, company, position, inviteUrl, idToken, authToken;

        $('input:checked').each(function () {
            name = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.publicUrl a').text();
            location = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.location').text();
            industry = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.industry').text();
            company = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.company').text();
            position = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.position').text();
            publicUrl = $(this).closest('tr').find(' td.publicUrl a').prop('href');
            inviteUrl = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.inviteLink a').prop('href');
            inviteUrl = text.match(/&id\=([^&]+)/);
            idToken = match[1];
        });

        alert(idToken);
```

It doesnt alert anything at all.

This is the error. I can't understand the error because I already declared it and it has value:

[image: Error Problem]

Comment: This screams out for a loop, and caching of `$(this).closest('tr')`.

Comment: hehe. I know sir, it's not the best code, but my current problem is the reg ex in javascript :D

Comment: Hint: You're accessing `match[1]`, when `match` is not a thing.

Comment: the alert doesn't fire at all or the alert has nothing as a value?

Comment: Why the downvote? Just asking, what's wrong?.

@gloomy.penguin - yes sir, it doesnt alert at all. Then when i delete the code from the text.match, and alert something else, it alerts the value, but if i put the code like that. It doesn't alert anything at all, even when i set for example alert(name);

Comment: @meagar - yes sir, i've mislooked it, i've change it to. inviteUrlA = text.match(...);, then idToken = inviteUrlA[1], alert the idToken, nothing still alerts.

Comment: Do some debugging for yourself. You have errors in your console, so fix them.

Comment: it's telling me "inviteUrl is undefined", but how come, i've declared it already and if i alert the value of inviteUrl, the link will come up.

Comment: What your `$profile_url` contains that you want `regex` for ?

Comment: Looks like `http://somedomain.com&id=123`, right ?

Comment: its $inviteUrl sir. example record contains "http://www.linkedin.com/people/invite?from=profile&key=211773644&authToken=88_h&authType=name" So i need to get the value after the key and authtoken, i already have the reg ex on it from php

Comment: @ArmanJonVillalobos, Sorry for the delay, check the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this (to get the query string values of `key` and `authToken`)

```
var str = "http://www.linkedin.com/people/invite?from=profile&key=211773644&authToken=88_h&authType=name%22";

var key = str.match(/key=([^&]+)/);
console.log(key[1]); // 211773644

var auth = str.match(/authToken=([^&]+)/);
console.log(auth[1]); // 88_h
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/EeZkE/1/)

Comment: Sir i've tried to fit my code to yours :
`code 
inviteUrl = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.inviteLink a').prop('href');
inviteId = inviteUrl.match(/key=(^&]+)/);
idToken = inviteId[1]; 
alert(idToken);
`
nothing alerts :/

Comment: Sorry! I can't say anything about it because i don't know about your `html`. You asked only for the `regex`.

Comment: Check your console to find the error.

Comment: Also make sure your `inviteUrl` variable contains `url` string.

Comment: it keeps saying that inviteUrl is not defined, But how can't it be not defined? x.x

Comment: what do u mean url string?. because if i alert the inviteUrl, im getting that link.